# Grails 2.0 unit test using @TestFor and @Mixin

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mixins, grails-2.0

I commonly use Mixins in test code to share utility methods across tests.  I have a test that I wrote which has a `@TestFor` and `@Mixin`.  The behavior that I'm seeing is that when I have the `@TestFor` annotation the test does not see my `@Mixin` code and gives me a MissingMethodException when executed.  When I remove the `@TestFor` it works fine.  Below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do.

```
@Mixin(TagLibTestUtils)
@TestFor(ErrorMessageTagLib)
class ErrorMessageTagLibTests {

    @Test
    void stuff() {
        something()
    }
}

class TagLibTestUtils {

    def something() {
        println ">>> HERE"
    }
}
```

So my question is do `@Mixin` and `@TestFor` annotations not work together?  Or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using Grails 2.0, you should `@TestMixin` instead of `@Mixin`.

If you look at the [source for the `TestFor`](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-testing/src/main/groovy/grails/test/mixin/TestFor.java), you will see this comment:

```
/**
 * Used to indicate the class under test. Triggers the @TestMixin AST transform for the given artefact type.
 *
 * @author Graeme Rocher
 * @since 2.0
 */
```

Comment: That works, thank you!  Any insight on why the change was made to force the use of TestMixin?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. Possibly they needed a different [RetentionPolicy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) than what is set for @Mixin. Maybe they just wanted it to be a part of the `grails.test` package rather than `groovy.lang`

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I'll award you the bounty tomorrow once it allows me to do so :)